# ExtLib, iNotes List View: how can I access data selected in the view from the outside?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

Using Firebug I found that the iNotes List View object has a function called "getSelectedData()" delivering something like an array of selected view entries (each one consisting of the item specific row data, like the "ext" element described [here](http://www.intec.co.uk/inotes-list-view-inotes-calendar-view-accessing-the-object/) by Paul Withers). Thus, using one of List View's internal events (like "onContextMenu"), I can retrive selected data and put them somewhere else. Which is just great!

But, as I'm never content with what I have, now I'm looking for a way to address the List View's object from the ***outside*** (e.g. using a button) to access a selected data collection in a similar or even the same way. But no matter what I try, I can't seem to get to the proper object from outside of the List View itself. Using

```
dojo.byId("#{id:listView1}")
```

is giving me an object but without any of those specific methods that I need. Neither Google, nor openNtf or the ExtLib book itself has any info on that.

Any hint?

Greets,
Lothar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I solved it. I've been close yesterday, but using ***dojo***.byId instead of ***dijit***.byId prevented it from working:

```
var grid = dijit.byId("#{id:listView1}"); 
var sel = grid.getSelectedData();
```

Result is a named array of row data where each row entry contains all the relevant view entry data for that row.

Works like a charm!
- Lothar